# No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first

Tags: c#

I want to transfer data in one row from `datagridview1` to `datagridview2`, but when I run this code it show like this

> (Additional information: No row can be added to a DataGridView control
>   that does not have columns. Columns must be added first).

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            DataGridViewRow r = dgvr.Clone() as DataGridViewRow;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvr.Cells)
            {
                r.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dgvr);
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(r);
        }
```

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear on what the problem is. Do you really not understand it?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because you have to add columns before inserting the rows into the GridView. Use `table.Columns.Add()` before `foreach` loop with your columns as its parameters .