# No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to insert data from an external form from textboxes, but I keep getting the error in the title. I made the modifier public for the datagridtable, but it still won't work. The table already has existing columns.

Form1

```
                Main man = new Main();
                var table = man.bunifuDataGridView1;
                table.Rows.Add(bunifuTextBox1.Text, bunifuTextBox2.Text, bunifuTextBox3.Text);
```

Form 2

```
            bunifuDataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            bunifuDataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Website";
            bunifuDataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Username";
            bunifuDataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Password";
            bunifuDataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690143/no-row-can-be-added-to-a-datagridview-control-that-does-not-have-columns-column

Comment: The code of Form2 is written in Form_Load event? Are you sure that this code is executed before you try to add row to the Gridview?

Comment: What is `Main man = new Main()` doing? Is that Class/Form(?) adding columns to the grid?

Comment: _but it still won't work_ -  This is not a helpful problem description! - Do you get errors? Compiler? Runtime? No result? Wrong result?

Comment: @soulja:       Please make sure you are adding the code to the proper event.